# Specifying font sizes

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I am trying to change the font size of my document to 8pt.

However I can not get it to take effect. I am trying it in the `\documentclass` declaration.

Should it be specified elsewhere?

I am using XeTeX and `fontspec`, if that is relevant.

Comment: No problem, but I was unable to find it through searching.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic font sizes of the standard document classes are built into the classes themselves. The `extsizes` classes define a number of parallel classes to the standard ones with a variety of sizes, including 8 pt.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle} % or {scrartcl} (Koma class)
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for random text
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The since all sizes of other text (such as `\Large`, `\footnotesize` etc.) are defined relative to the document class size, it's better to use this sort of solution, if the normal document classes work for you.

The `memoir` class also allows a 9pt option, but not 8pt.

The `koma` document classes also allow specifying an arbitrary point size.

Comment: Exactly like I wanted.