# Specifying percent of font size (as normalsize)

Tags: fontsize

I'm trying to replicate the format/style of a document, and I got somewhat stuck at specifying font size, which it turns out, isn't all that easy (if you want to keep `\normalsize`, `\large` etc for font sizes different from 10, 11, or 12 - or if you mess with margins):

- [Re: Changing default font size](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3477#p13592) (on LaTeX-Community.org)
- [How can I redefine the base font size and change the size of the page number on chapter pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12380/how-can-i-redefine-the-base-font-size-and-change-the-size-of-the-page-number-on-c/12403#12403)
- [Specifying font sizes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10433/specifying-font-sizes/10438#10438)
- [How to specify font size less than 10pt (or more than 12pt)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt)

For me, the problem is that it seems I need to have the Palatino font between sizes 8pt and 9pt; but since specific files are being loaded (and `lineskip`s calculated) from specific files related to these sizes (e.g. `latex/extsizes/size8.clo`), I can't just put in "8.5pt". Here's my example so far:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{geometry}

% specify new page size - ripped from geometry package:
\makeatletter
\@namedef{Gm@envelope6x9paper}#1{\Gm@setsize{#1}(6,9){in}}%
% % ‘paper' = paper takes a paper name as its value.
\define@key{Gm}{paper}{\setkeys{Gm}{#1}}%
\let\KV@Gm@papername\KV@Gm@paper
% The following paper names are available.
\define@key{Gm}{envelope6x9paper}[true]{\Gm@setpaper@ifpre{envelope6x9paper}}%
\makeatother

\geometry{envelope6x9paper, inner=0.6in, outer=1in, twoside=true, top=1in, bottom=1in}

\usepackage{mathpazo} % palatino; no [scaled=0.92]
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{*0}

\title{My New Document Class Test}
\author{Testus}

\begin{document}

% to match comparison PDF:
% increase page counter once, so we start on even page (that would be open left, presumably)
\stepcounter{page}

\maketitle% Actually makes a title page

\section{Intro}
\lipsum[1-4]

\section{More stuff}
\lipsum[5-9]

\end{document}
```

I was thinking - if I could "scale" the "default" font size; presumably that would "propagate" to all the line spacings too; but unfortunately, `mathpazo` doesn't have a `[scaled]` option (like `helvet`, I guess).

So is there a LaTeX way (for the time being, I'd like to avoid switching to KOMA-Script), so that the above example can be modified in the preamble, such that the normal size of the used font becomes 150% bigger than the originally loaded font (*with which, I expect, I would get approximately something like 8.5 pt - if I load 8pt*)?

EDIT: Just found [Continuously-sizable fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21826/continuously-sizable-fonts/21828#21828), and tried to use [`scalefnt`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/carlisle/):

```
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\scalefont{1.5}
```

... but it seems to have no effect above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I found a rather good explanation here: [LaTeX Community • View topic - Font Sizes](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=14031#p52901):

> size10.clo defines
>   `\newcommand\Huge{\@setfontsize\Huge\@xxvpt{30}}`
>   The macro \@xxvpt, which looks like roman representation of arabic 25pt, is defined in latex.ltx:
>   `\def\@xxvpt{24.88}`
>   Similar for the other values.

... and so, if one checks the `size8.clo` - it similarly defines all of the parameters, more or less, explicitly - instead of relatively (which the original post assumes).

So probably the plain Latex way would be to copy the size8.clo into a new file, and then change all parameters there (and then load the new size / changed file)... but that's gonna be some work :)

If anyone's got anything easier, please post :)